# Rhythmbox won't import or play flac files

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, flac

I have a new installation of 12.04 and I just copied over all my music to the ~/Music folder. Rhythmbox found all the mp3 and ogg files, but it refuses to import flac files. They simply do not appear in my music library.

If I start Rhythmbox on the command line and try to import a folder that contains flac files, absolutely nothing happens. Nothing is imported; no error messages.

I have all the dependencies for Rhythmbox installed, along with all the suggested and recommended packages. I can play a flac file with gst-launch-0.10 and gst-typefind-0.10 correctly identifies flac files as audo/x-flac.

Why does Rhythmbox refuse to see flac files? What can I do to find out what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Please give us the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep -i flac` so we can see whether you've got the correct libraries installed or not.

For reference, I'm running Ubuntu Precise, and I have:

```
me~banshee:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep flac
flac                            install
libflac8                        install
libflac8:i386                   install
```

... and Rhythmbox plays flac fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the version of Rhythmbox which doesen't play FLAC.

Try installing `libflac`